# Powershell script to compare AD computers to text file and change registry service on those computer and then write the computers that were offline

Tags: powershell, active-directory, registry

I'm trying to filter out computers that have already ran the script (that enables remote registry service) within AD from a list in a text file

```
$NamesFromFile = Get-Content 
C:\scripts\Inventory\offlineRemoteRegStartupWorkstations.txt

$computers = get-adcomputer -Filter * | Where-Object { 
$_.Name.SubString(1) -in $NamesFromFile } 
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{ 
if (Test-Connection -count 1 -computer $computer.Name -quiet){ 
Write-Host "Updating system" $computer.Name "....." -ForegroundColor 
Green 
Set-Service –Name remoteregistry –Computer $computer.Name -StartupType 
Automatic 
Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer.Name | start-service 
} 
else 
{ 
Write-Host "System Offline " $computer.Name "....." -ForegroundColor Red 
echo $computer.Name >> C:\scripts\Inventory\offlineRemoteRegStartup.txt} 
}
```

no errors just blank

Comment: Why $_.name.substring(1) instead of just $_.name?

Comment: If you check `$computers` after running the script, is it empty?

Comment: this >>> `Where-Object {$_.Name.SubString(1) -in $NamesFromFile}` <<< is doing a test for an EXACT MATCH of the 1st letter in the current computer name with any one _ENTIRE ITEM_ in the `$NamesFromFile` collection. that seems likely to ALWAYS be false. [*grin*]

Comment: If `$computers` is not empty, try changing `$computer.Name` to `$($computer.Name)` everywhere you use it.

Comment: sorry for the late response. @Theo worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a re-write of your script.

Because you test if only the first character of the computer name is in the list of computers, your `$computers` variable will remain empty, so nothing happens.

Also, I think it would be wise to add a check if the startup type of the RemoteRegistry service is not already set to Automatic, because after all.. the computernames you read in from the file may not be accurate.

To avoid having to use `$computer.Name` all the time, I use a `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`, so we only have to run through a list of strings.

```
$NamesFromFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\scripts\Inventory\offlineRemoteRegStartupWorkstations.txt' | Sort-Object -Unique

Get-ADComputer -Filter * | 
    Where-Object { $NamesFromFile -contains $_.Name } |  # if the computer name is in the list
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |                 # we're only interested in the Name property
    ForEach-Object {
        # the automatic variable '$_' represents a single computername from the list
        if (Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName $_ -Quiet) {
            # test if the RemoteRegistry service startup type is not already Automatic
            # you can do the same with (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='RemoteRegistry'" -ComputerName $_)
            # only slower..
            if ((Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='RemoteRegistry'" -ComputerName $_).StartMode -ne 'Auto') {
                Write-Host "Updating system '$_'....." -ForegroundColor Green
                Set-Service –Name RemoteRegistry –Computer $_ -StartupType Automatic
                Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry –Computer $_ | Start-Service
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "RemoteRegistry service startup type already Automatic on computer '$_'....." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "System Offline '$_'....." -ForegroundColor Red
            Add-Content -Path 'C:\scripts\Inventory\offlineRemoteRegStartup.txt' -Value $_
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked beautifully. I'm new to powershell so most of my code is usually strung up of previous code. thanks again